# Verificar se processo está em execução sem esbarrar no limite de 15 caracteres

Tags: bash, refatoração, processo

Com o seguinte código verificamos se determinado processo se encontra em execução:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Verificar se processo abc está em execução
if pgrep "abc" >/dev/null 2>&1
  then
     printf "Está em execução.\n" >&2
  else
     printf "Não está em execução.\n" >&2
fi
exit
```

Mas se o nome do processo tiver mais de 15 caracteres, por exemplo `abcdefghijklmnop`, vou obter sempre `Não está em execução.` porque o [`pgrep`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pgrep) falha devido ao limite de 15 caracteres oriundo do limite de tamanho no campo *comm* dos ficheiros em `/proc/[pid]/stat`.

## Pergunta

Como posso refatorar o código em cima com vista a ultrapassar o limite dos 15 caracteres ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De acordo com as notas no manual do [pgrep](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pgrep) deve-se usar a opção `-f` para o comando.

> O padrão normalmente só é comparado com o nome do processo. Quando `-f` está definido, toda linha de comando é usada na comparação.